# How can men become pregnant?

Tags: obstetrics, male, uterus

Apparently men can get pregnant now? I'm a man; how can I have a baby? I don't have a uterus; doesn't that mean I can't be pregnant?

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently men can get pregnant now?

Yes, in two very different cases:

Trans men can have a uterus, can get pregnant and bear children.

It is theoretically possible for an XY male to have an embryo implanted in their abdomen and it to develop as an ectopic pregnancy.  This is discussed in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Male_pregnancy#Ectopic_implant), and as they highlight that it is only a theoretical possibility, it would probably be fatal for both the parent and child:

> Robert Winston, a pioneer of in-vitro fertilization, told London's Sunday Times that "male pregnancy would certainly be possible" by having an embryo implanted in a man's abdomen – with the placenta attached to an internal organ such as the bowel – and later delivered surgically. Ectopic implantation of the embryo along the abdominal wall, and resulting placenta growth would, however, be very dangerous and potentially fatal for the host, and is therefore unlikely to be studied in humans

Comment: While I don't doubt Prof Winston's credentials or his expertise, I think his statement could do with a gigantic "Citation Needed" sticker - I've found nothing reputable on this at all - not even in animal research. Though having said that, it is the male seahorse that gestates the eggs in a special brood pouch.

Comment: I would add a third possibility which is an intersex person who is not trans